# How can I move my content image upper in React Native styling?

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, styles, accordion

So here is what I currently have:

[image]

It's happening because of the shadow headbox:

[image]

So how can I move my image upper? I've tried to implement this by doing so: `marginTop: -30,` or so:
`transform: [{ translateY: -30 }]`, and here is what I'm getting:

[image]

Any solutions on this?

Comment: Include your code so a definite answer can be given

Answer (score 0):

After using negative margin-top. Use `position: relative; z-index: 1;`